# pass GET variables when using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php

after submitting a form I get redirected to the same page because I settled the form action as `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` but I've got the problem I need to be redirected to the full url which pass the id and cat GET variables.

I think I can easily solve it by adding to the server variable something like

```
.'?id='.$_GET['id'].'&cat='.$_GET['cat']
```

but I would like to know if there is something similar to `PHP_SELF`, but which keep the full url with the GET variables.

Comment: if you leave out the action/url the form will be submitted to the current URL. you should get the params with it. I'd consider sending them with post though. If there aren't any spesific reasons you want the params in the address field.

Comment: Do a `print_r($_SERVER);` to determine the best variable to use. Generally you'll have access to the full requested URL including query-string parameters and hash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Get the Full URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url)

Answer (score 5):

You can just put an empty form action like in the following example:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

All GET parameters will be preserved

Answer (score 1):

The form submit to the current page by default.
You could try:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="some"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="value"/>
</form>

domain.com/?id=some&cat=value
```

Comment: thanks, but my question was different, I already had a way to pass again the data, adding again the values to the url. I was asking if is there any shorter way whith a server variable different from php_self

Comment: @Jasper told the best way to discover which variable you need.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sending method of the form from POST to GET.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: There is absolutely no need to do that